# How to modify the WooCommerce 'order review' at checkout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

This is irritating. Last year it was no problem for me to customize the order review area at checkout, but a few updates later and it isn't working. I have disabled all plugins except WC and using a basic theme and this still is happening.

When I use my custom loaded JS to change part of the order review area, the change takes place, but then it auto refreshes itself for no reason at all and the change is gone. No matter where I put the JS, or if I set priority to max, the area always updates itself somehow and I can't change anything without disabling the wc-checkout script, which is needed. Any ideas how to achieve this?

I tried searching everywhere for a filter for when the area is refreshed but found nothing except for individual item name filters or for quantities.

Comment: "change part of the order review area"... What are you trying to change?

Comment: Modify the item name when specific items come up and/or when certain quantities are met. Also adding in a new row following specific items.  All of which I had done before many times with older versions of WC.

Answer (score 0):

The filters are all in the order-review templates I think. For example, you can change the title of an item in the order review section when the item's quantity is greater than 10:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'so_29985124_order_item_title', 10, 2 );
function so_29985124_order_item_title( $title, $order_item ) {

    if ( $order_item[ 'qty' ] > 10 ) ) {
        $title = "Mega quantities of " . $title;
    }

    return $title;
}
```